# How to enable fade effect on Twitter Bootstrap tooltip?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to implement Twitter Bootstrap tooltips on my website, however the fade effects are not working. When I hover over whatever element I want to have the tooltip, the tooltip just appears and disappears accordingly, without the fade effect that Twitter demonstrates on their [site](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips).

Here is what my code looks like:

jQuery:

```
jQuery(function () {
    jQuery('[data-toggle=tooltip]').tooltip();
});
```

HTML:

```
<span href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Tooltip showing">
   stranger
</span>
```

I would very much like the fade effect to appear when hovering over this element. I tried both in Firefox and Chrome, and the fade effect does not work.

Comment: Your code is fine. Can you make a fiddle that reproduces your issue?

Comment: @RalphDavidAbernathy -- you forgot to add the component animations in your customized file.

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/customize/?id=0702025dd2ed59784a91 - missing

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the [Bootstrap docs on Tooltips](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#tooltips-options), you can do that by setting the `animation` option to `true`, either with the *attribute* (**`data-animation="true"`**) or as part of the initialization *options* (**`{animation: true}`**).

So you can update your HTML like this:

```html
<span href="#" class="tip"
      title="Tooltip showing"
      data-toggle="tooltip" 
      data-placement="top"
      data-animation="true" >
    stranger
</span>
```

Or add in your initializtion code like this:

```js
$('.tip').tooltip({animation: true});
```

***Hint***: Using a class instead of a data attribute in your jQuery selector is much more performant.

#### [Demo in jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/macsupport/hbm7tozn/5/)

Comment: I am sorry, but this does not work. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: Yes, I am loading jQuery before bootstrap.js

Comment: Thank you. I have the same exact code, but it is still not working. Do you think something may be conflicting with the fade in/our effect of the tooltip?

Comment: couldn't answer without a fiddle or link

Comment: Here is a link to my site where the tooltip fade effect does not work:
http://obliviga.com/test2/

Comment: @RalphDavidAbernathy -- you forgot to add the component animations in your customized file.

Comment: When you customize bootstrap, you need to add the appropriate plugins ----> Transitions (required for any kind of animation)

Comment: Your script has a few errors, try this '$('.tooltip').tooltip({
    placement: 'right',
    html: true,
animation: true  
});'